# When adding a confidence interval "manually", doesn't visually appear to cover most cases

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, nonlinear-regression

I have a non linear regression model that is based on an exponential decay function. When I try to add a confidence interval, instead of using the models in built 'confidence interval' prediction functionality, I wanted to do so manually. I get my model params and their standard errors, then calculate the prediction using the param +/- 2 standard errors. The plot I work on in the code below shows my final result. Expectation was to have a upper and lower confidence interval line encompassing most of the data, but instead it looks like it just passes through the middle.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
example_data <- dput(example_data)
structure(list(cohort_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "factor"), billing_cycle = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), sample_survival_rate = c(0.630375321185327, 
0.467011817658967, 0.365716219971609, 0.320696843452609, 0.289715829574683, 
0.274138331734878, 0.263859709445232, 0.257975988868186, 0.25428803817773, 
0.253349513689708, 0.251974683159173, 0.25087864807282, 0.626381321766971, 
0.457700237294344, 0.37100891459414, 0.322040406927193, 0.294130414649021, 
0.273224287881716, 0.264008524367158, 0.257890204475791, 0.254600100163038, 
0.252665019457592, 0.250872931127164, 0.249283495816814, 0.617466244254771, 
0.463682683415105, 0.371605156168376, 0.320962165438288, 0.294378622257423, 
0.272094922902315, 0.263553461969235, 0.258151398805649, 0.254228898501473, 
0.252721988646528, 0.250957888359671, 0.250678608369381, 0.625842284676012, 
0.475715043015969, 0.364457416055596, 0.326485932788029, 0.287971100886182, 
0.272805038087397, 0.263982745776158, 0.258071343467853, 0.254782618390382, 
0.252538854336153, 0.251931200298009, 0.250189014687092, 0.614958361152235, 
0.474023154666957, 0.37790296469348, 0.321305725376115, 0.288431205767636, 
0.273448941036557, 0.265221683162653, 0.257977862090824, 0.254402493942438, 
0.252262229858011, 0.252482170616736, 0.250167038793874, 0.615276997378503, 
0.462251124297695, 0.379117488405097, 0.320048927623227, 0.286479327627075, 
0.277112140101815, 0.264517062972436, 0.257970078541396, 0.254324910083164, 
0.253199527200694, 0.250985688661134, 0.251435584163309, 0.626165857232067, 
0.457716584851464, 0.380706922662529, 0.32214396867372, 0.28725348189702, 
0.274217428106078, 0.262850951863544, 0.258008309979443, 0.253982997355457, 
0.252432836066219, 0.252955446219195, 0.250173801962517, 0.626248558471049, 
0.474358329360571, 0.369797644382662, 0.324484196652504, 0.292835709935179, 
0.274812679385776, 0.264902105112049, 0.257920928121361, 0.254293689364316, 
0.252094179645866, 0.25146035913424, 0.251382845450947, 0.619935506915612, 
0.472368360759675, 0.376906826285281, 0.322622472724279, 0.294056956175115, 
0.2762753843963, 0.263543866656661, 0.257911561154227, 0.254082172527871, 
0.252479306436864, 0.25092022041681, 0.25147680046597, 0.620940410953731, 
0.458684083447818, 0.367775959111921, 0.31955299117994, 0.290834501870578, 
0.273073930174107, 0.264099158034426, 0.258049918137067, 0.254097282656084, 
0.252593088721244, 0.251201515264958, 0.249725999038376, 0.6178781171174, 
0.480537380689229, 0.370305282109615, 0.321910535895373, 0.295165049355668, 
0.274898706563092, 0.264775605155201, 0.257970685836666, 0.254379583052875, 
0.25230912983428, 0.251323575117219, 0.250613209856686, 0.627625590735999, 
0.470453669107974, 0.361352411452518, 0.329163446065758, 0.293046687979046, 
0.275398723193211, 0.263940477049976, 0.257914465199765, 0.254451201344154, 
0.251946651930126, 0.251414402429264, 0.252082405269007)), row.names = c(NA, 
-144L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The above block creates a data frame example_data. Here's a plot of the fields of interest:

```
survival_plot <- example_data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = billing_cycle, y = sample_survival_rate, color = cohort_id)) +
  geom_line()
survival_plot
```

[image]

Then I fit a model. After fitting I retrieve the model params `i`, `a` and `lambda` along with their standard errors, then I (attempt to) add an upper and lower bound confidence interval:

```
# function
exponential_decay <- function(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle) i + a * exp(-lambda * billing_cycle)

mod.nls <- nls(sample_survival_rate ~ 
                 exponential_decay(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle), data = example_data, start = list(i = 0.5, a = 0.5, lambda = 0.15))

mod_summary <- mod.nls |> summary()

mod_i <- coef(mod.nls)['i']
mod_i_se <- mod_summary$coefficients["i", "Std. Error"]
mod_a <- coef(mod.nls)['a']
mod_a_se <- mod_summary$coefficients["a", "Std. Error"]
mod_lambda <- coef(mod.nls)['lambda']
mod_lambda_se <- mod_summary$coefficients["lambda", "Std. Error"]

# add 95% CI to example data
example_data <- example_data |> 
  mutate(
    mod_upper_ci = exponential_decay(mod_i + 2*(mod_i_se), mod_a + 2*(mod_a_se), mod_lambda + 2*(mod_lambda_se), billing_cycle),
    mod_lower_ci = exponential_decay(mod_i - 2*(mod_i_se), mod_a - 2*(mod_a_se), mod_lambda - 2*(mod_lambda_se), billing_cycle)
    )
```

But when I add the upper/lower interval to my plot I get this:

```
survival_plot +
  geom_line(aes(x = billing_cycle, y = mod_upper_ci), color = 'black') +
  geom_line(aes(x = billing_cycle, y = mod_lower_ci), color = 'black')
```

[image]

Does this look 'right'? I expected the black lines to encompass the cohort_ids, instead it looks like it's just going through the middle.

Is my approach flawed (presumably yes)? How can I correctly add a 95% confidence interval to my plot using the model params and their standard errors?

Comment: If I understand your data correctly, the `cohort_ids` are basically your data points. The 95% CI is the CI on the _mean_. It isn't a prediction interval. The prediction interval should cover the data. The CI just covers the mean. So it's probably doing the right thing (I can't reproduce your modelling from the code given in the question)

Comment: [More on the difference between CIs and PIs here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info)

Comment: Thanks for the info here @AlexJ. Cohort_Ids are like an observation at different values of billing cycles, context is cohort survival over time. Is it possible to use the model params to 'manually' get a prediction interval? I'm keen to try this without just using the models in built functionality.

Comment: " can't reproduce your modelling from the code given in the question" I think that with nls, it converges, so there might be slight differences depending on the seed before running nls(). Unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: What I mean by reproducibility, is that for example you haven't included how `exponential_decay` function is defined

Comment: Re: prediction interval https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_of_the_mean_and_predicted_responses#Variance_of_the_predicted_response?

Comment: Ah, I have edited it now to include the function definition `
exponential_decay <- function(i, a, lambda, billing_cycle) i + a * exp(-lambda * billing_cycle)
`